# Add/fill pandas column based on range in rows from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Working with pandas, I have df1 indexed by time samples:

```
data = '''\
time       flags    input                  
8228835.0  53153.0  32768.0
8228837.0  53153.0  32768.0
8228839.0  53153.0  32768.0
8228841.0  53153.0  32768.0
8228843.0  61345.0  32768.0'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df1 = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+', index_col='time')
```

df2 indicates time ranges with start and end to define ranges where the state of 'check' is True:

```
data = '''\
        check     start       end
20536   True   8228837   8228993
20576   True   8232747   8232869
20554   True   8230621   8230761
20520   True   8227351   8227507
20480   True   8223549   8223669
20471   True   8221391   8221553'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df2 = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+')
```

What I need to do is add a column for 'check' to df1 and fill out the actual time ranges defined in df2 with the value of True. All others should be False. An example result would be:

```
             flags    input    check
time                       
8228835.0  53153.0  32768.0    False
8228837.0  53153.0  32768.0    True
8228839.0  53153.0  32768.0    True
8228841.0  53153.0  32768.0    True
8228843.0  61345.0  32768.0    True
....
8228994.0. 12424.0. 32768.0.   False
```

Comment: Why is 8228835 `True`? I don't see any ranges in `df2` including this number.

Comment: Probably just a type error.

Comment: Correct - typo on my part.

Comment: For latecomers, the part that constructs the DataFrame needs to be updated. Specifically, use "import io" and "fileobj = io.StringIO (data)" instead of "pd.compat.StringIO (data)" because of "AttributeError: module ' 'pandas.compat' has no attribute 'StringIO ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a list or ranges, and then use [`pd.Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

df2 = df2[df2['check']]

ranges = map(range, df2['start'], df2['end'])

df1['check'] = df1.index.isin(chain.from_iterable(ranges))

print(df1)

             flags    input  check
time                              
8228835.0  53153.0  32768.0  False
8228837.0  53153.0  32768.0   True
8228839.0  53153.0  32768.0   True
8228841.0  53153.0  32768.0   True
8228843.0  61345.0  32768.0   True
```

Comment: Never thought you can chain the range like this , nice one dude !!

Comment: @Wen, It's news to me too. I can only assume `chain.from_iterable(ranges)` is called *each* time. Because it's an iterator you can't reuse it, so a new iterator is used each time. I hope someone times these solutions, your `IntervalIndex` looks neat!

Comment: Or, more likely, there's some list conversion going on, which is inefficient :(.

Comment: @jpp - this worked with a minor modification to the assignment. I edited your answer to match what worked for me. Wall time across ~1.8M rows on this sample data was 3.74 seconds. Thanks for pointing me in this direction!

Comment: @schwim, Sure, I've improved your edit [because chained assignment is discouraged in the docs].

Comment: @jpp, I've got a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51825533/3279716) but I can't use ranges as the intervals are floats. Do you know how to make it work with floats?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can using `IntervalIndex` with `loc`

```
df2.index=pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2.start,df2.end,'both')
df2.loc[df.index]
Out[174]: 
        check  start  end
[1, 2]   True      1    2
[4, 5]   True      4    5
[7, 8]   True      7    8
df['newcol']=df2.loc[df.index].check.values.tolist()
df
Out[176]: 
       flags    input  newcol
flags                        
2          2  32768.0    True
4          4  32768.0    True
7          7  32768.0    True
```

Comment: I get `KeyError` at the `df2.loc[df.index]` part. Need to noodle on this one a bit more...

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension using `any()`. No clue about the actual performance though, would be nice if you could run the %timings for us!

```
df1['check'] = [any(start <= i <= end for start,end in 
                    zip(df2['start'], df2['end'])) for i in df1.index]

print(df1)
```

Returns:

```
             flags    input  check
time                              
8228835.0  53153.0  32768.0  False
8228837.0  53153.0  32768.0   True
8228839.0  53153.0  32768.0   True
8228841.0  53153.0  32768.0   True
8228843.0  61345.0  32768.0   True
```

Comment: Neat idea, and thank you! Unfortunately, df1 is upwards of 2 million rows. I shortened it down to 10k rows and this loop took 43 seconds to finish. The result was not a close match to the df2 ranges.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I was looking for a more general solution, that allowed to copy any columns from the interval array over to the "normal" indexed array (and not just set a bool flag).

For this I modified the IntervalIndex approach, which seems to work really nicely. I have not timed the results, though!

Note, that you can play around with the `closed` argument for the `IntervalIndex` depending on your requirements

```py
import pandas as pd


def merge_from_interval(data, interval_array, start_col, end_col, colnames):
    interval_array_with_index = interval_array.copy()

    interval_array_with_index.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(interval_array[start_col], interval_array[end_col], closed="left")

    data_merged = data.merge(interval_array_with_index.reindex(data.index)[colnames], left_index=True, right_index=True)
    return data_merged


intervals = pd.DataFrame({"start": [3, 6], "end": [5, 15], "value": [1, 2]})

data = pd.DataFrame(list(range(20)))

merge_from_interval(data, intervals, "start", "end", ["value"])
```