# Get values from one dataframe where they are between an interval in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe containing a numeric (float) series and a categorical ID (`df`). How can I create a dictionary in the form `'key': []` where the key is an ID from the dataframe and the list contains the difference between the numbers in the separate dataframes?

I have managed this using loops though I am looking for a more pandas way of doing this.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.75435, 0.74897, 0.60949,
                         0.87438, 0.90885, 0.28547,
                         0.27327, 0.31078, 0.15576,
                         0.58139],
                   'id': list('aaaxxbbyyy')})
rl = pd.DataFrame({'b': [0.51, 0.30], 'id': ['aaa', 'bbb']})
interval = 0.1
d = defaultdict(list)
for index, row in rl.iterrows():
    before = df[df['a'].between(row['b'] - interval, row['b'], inclusive=False)]
    after = df[df['a'].between(row['b'], row['b'] + interval, inclusive=True)]
    for x, b_row in before.iterrows():
        d[b_row['id']].append((b_row['a'] - row['b']))
    for x, a_row in after.iterrows():
        d[a_row['id']].append((a_row['a'] - row['b']))
for k, v in d.items():
    print('{k}\t{v}'.format(k=k, v=len(v)))
a   1
y   2
b   2
d
defaultdict(list,
        {'a': [0.09948],
         'b': [-0.01452, -0.02672],
         'y': [0.07138, 0.01078]})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663572/add-fill-pandas-column-based-on-range-in-rows-from-another-dataframe

Comment: @Wen, could you expand on what you would do? I can't seem to get these to work. I get a `KeyError` using your answer and can't use floats in the ranges with jpp's answer.