# label intervals based on other intervals in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two dataframes, `a` and `b`

`b` has a datetime index, while `a` has a `Start` and `End` datetime columns
I need to 'Label' to `True`, all the rows of `b` whose indexes fall within any `[Start,End]` intervals from `a`

Right now I doing:

```
for _,r in a.iterrows():
    b.loc[np.logical_and(b.index>=r.Start,
                                    b.index<=r.End),'Label']=True
```

but this is extremely slow when b is large.

How to optimize the provided code snippet?

MVCE:

```
b=pd.DataFrame(index=[pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01')],columns=['Label'])

  a=pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{'Start':pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01'),'End':pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01')}])
```

EDIT:

the solution at
 [Add/fill pandas column based on range in rows from another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663572/add-fill-pandas-column-based-on-range-in-rows-from-another-dataframe) 
does not work for me (they use range to fill the intervals, while we are working on datetime

Comment: can we get a mcve? :) Thanks

Comment: There are datetimes with no times in real data?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution using `apply` -

Dummy CSV data

```
Date,Start,End
01-08-2019,01-02-2019, 01-10-2019
01-08-2019,01-02-2020, 01-10-2020
```

Code

```
df = pd.read_csv('dummy.csv').apply(pd.to_datetime)
df.T.apply(lambda x: x[1] < x[0] and x[2] > x[0])
```

Result

```
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing something like this?

```
def func(): # b.index
    mask = (a['Start'] > date) & (a['End'] <= date)
    df = a.loc[mask]
    if len(df) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

b['Label'] = b.index().to_series().apply(func)
```